# How does the `new` keyword work in this Ruby method definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

Railscasts put out a great episode on refactoring. One method is to move complex controller logic into service objects instead of pushing it down the model. In [one service object](https://github.com/railscasts/398-service-objects/blob/master/auth-services/app/services/password_reset.rb), the following code is used:

```
class PasswordReset
  attr_reader :user

  def self.from_email(email)
    new User.find_by_email(email)
  end

  def self.from_token(token)
    new User.find_by_password_reset_token!(token)
  end
  ...
end
```

What does the `new` key word serve in both method bodies? `new User.find_by_`. How is that different from `User.find_by_` ?

Here's the calling code:

```
  def create # controller
    password_reset = PasswordReset.from_email(params[:email])
    if password_reset.user
      password_reset.send_email
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Email sent with password reset instructions."
    else
      redirect_to new_password_reset_url, alert: "Email address does not match a user account."
    end
  end
```

Also, why the `attr_reader :user` needed?

Comment: Can you rewrite the title so it reflects the ONE actual question you want to know about? You'll catch more fish by using bait that they find appealing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the classname is implicit in self methods. The code could have be written like:

```
 def self.from_email(email)
    PasswordReset.new User.find_by_email(email)
 end
```

To answer the 2nd half of your question, `attr_reader` defines an instance variable and a reader method (aka getter method if you're coming from java or c#). Putting it all together, you could have written it as :

```
class PasswordReset


  def user
    @user
  end

  def self.from_email(email)
    PasswordReset.new User.find_by_email(email)
  end

  def self.from_token(token)
    PasswordReset.new User.find_by_password_reset_token!(token)
  end
  ...
end
```

This is assuming PasswordReset#initialize takes a User as a parameter, and sets @user accordingly

Comment: @dae,  User.find_by_email(email) is argument for PasswordReset constructor.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you. It seems weird, though, that you are instantiating an object than instantiates itself. Is there a name for this pattern or is it normal? Sorry, I know I'm slow. I'm not used to thinking in Ruby, I guess. I assume the `attr_reader` returns `@user` or `nil`? Does it just look for something called `user` in the instance?

Comment: In a code review I'd even argue that using the bare `new` is non-intuitive and forces anyone doing support to read the whole method, and maybe even the class, just to see what's going on. Using `PasswordReset.new` is much clearer and self-documenting. Even `new(...)` with the parameter in parenthesis would have been an improvement, so -1 for whoever originally wrote the code, and +1 for suggesting a cleaner/clearer solution.

Comment: Would anyone be kind enough to answer my comment?

Comment: @theTinMan When you explicitly state the class, you prevent people to subclass the `PasswordReset` class and have the factory methods create instances of said subclass instead of the parent class. Also the methods are simple enough and appropriately named, I don't find anything wrong there... As for the parenthesis, I'm in favor of not removing all parenthesis, in this case however, given the long argument expression, parenthesis would make the statement not really more readable.

Comment: @theTinMan: If somebody doesn't know that `self` is the implicit receiver in Ruby, they probably shouldn't be doing support in the first place!

Comment: @HolgerJust would you be kind enough to provide a small example of how one would use this pattern with a factory?

Comment: @dee The [factory method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) is a way to implement a factory. In the case of this question, the class is basically its own Factory.